# Animated film where kid builds a castle by running and the bricks magically go under their feet

Tags: story-identification

When I was young I remember I watched an animated film where a kid built a castle by just running around and bricks magically placed themselves under their feet. What was the film called?

Comment: When were you "young?"  Approximately what year?  Was it a movie or a TV show?  You should check out the [suggestions for asking a good question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if it triggers anything else you can add.